# Using a legal WindowsXp key with a different Windows XP disk

Tags: windows-xp, serial

I'm trying to reinstall WindowsXp on a Acer PC of a friend of mine. Problem here is, it has a legal installation of WindowsXp, but the re-installation disk is nowhere to b found.

I have a legal copy of WindowsXp that came with my Dell PC. Can I use my CD to install WindowsXp and use the serial key of the ACER machine? Is this legal, or will I be breaking rules?

Answer (score 1):

See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/264868/how-to-obtain-and-re-install-windows-xp?rq=1) as well just for other references...

Anyways, you cannot use the Dell Windows CD, as it is made for the Dell system it was sold with. With Windows XP, there are three things you need to check the version for:

1. Edition (Home, Pro, Pro x64, MCE, Tablet, etc)
2. License Channel (OEM, Retail, Enterprise, etc)
3. Vanilla or special OEM. By Vanilla, I mean one that does not have ANY branding whatsoever from third party companies. These are the best.

If you have a special OEM disk, it expects certain hardware, and it will violate the EULA. It may work, but you will notice glitches if it does work. Your best bet is to go a computer shop, and ask for the regular Windows XP (edition) OEM installation disk. If they charge you more then $10, it's usually a rip off, as it's just burning a legit ISO image to the disk.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems unwarranted. He plans on using the Acer's own COA key on the Acer itself. Only problem is obtaining an OEM XP Acer/generic disc.

Comment: @karan misread the end of the question. Edited

Answer (score 0):

You need to copy the files and registry keys for recovery of activation.

files at `%windir%\system32`:

```
wpa.dbl
wpa.bak

dpcdll.dll
EULA.TXT
oembios.bin
oembios.cat
oembios.dat
oembios.sig
PID.INF
PIDGEN.DLL
SETUPP.INI
```

folder Windows Genuine:

```
"%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Windows Genuine Advantage"
```

registry:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Setup\Pid]
"Pid"="Your Pid Value"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion]
"ProductId"= ...
"DigitalProductId"= ...
"LicenseInfo"= ...
```

Save Windows XP serial number. Use GetProductKey.vbs:

```
cscript //nologo GetProductKey.vbs
```

Get script at

[Recovery Disk install to a specific partition](https://superuser.com/questions/617886/recovery-disk-install-to-a-specific-partition/617997)

Otherwise, you get a system that you can not activate the license key.

Yes, you are right to restore the operating system on the laptop.